# When confidence interval goes to infinity, what's the problem?

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test, assumptions

I run a Welch independent samples t-test and obtain the results of t(890.13) = 2.90, p < .01, but the 95% **confidence intervals are between 0.045 to infinity**.

```
t.test(y ~ A, paired = FALSE, alternative = "greater", data = data)
```

Does this necessarily mean that there is a problem? Do I go back to re-check that all the assumptions of the Welch t-test are met?

Comment: Did you by any chance calculate a one-sided confidence interval?

Comment: That was a one-sided test. Please present the exact command you used in R.

Comment: Edited. It was indeed a one-sided test. Appreciate any insights you may have.

Comment: Depend on which side you are looking at, a one-sided confidence interval is either of the form $(-\infty, c_1]$ or of the form $[c_2,\infty)$

Comment: I see! I got it now. Thank you @Henry